# How to use Artifactory Maven Build in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

i am trying to publish my build artifacts via artifactory maven to my artifactory server.

```
stage("${buildType} publish to Artifactory") {
        def server = Artifactory.server 'artifactory'
        def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
        rtMaven.resolver server: server, releaseRepo: 'libs-release', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot'
        rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'libs-release-local-SNAPSHOT'
        rtMaven.tool = 'maven tool name'
        def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean package -Dskip.unit.tests=true -Dskip.integration.tests=true'
        server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
    }
```

But the Job fails with

`ERROR: Couldn't find Maven executable.`

i tried to match the "maven tool name" with the name of maven in my jenkins tools, but it still doesn't work

Any help appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you "copy paste" the example without changing the variables. 
In order for it to work you will need to verify the following:

1. You will need to check what is the name of the Artifactory instance in the Jenkins system configuration page. The name is something that you gave it once configured Artifactory in Jenkins.

   This will be the value under 'Server ID'. This value should be placed instead the 'Artifactory' in:

   `def server = Artifactory.server 'artifactory'`
2. The `rtMaven.tool = 'maven tool name'` should also be replaced with the name you entered on the "Global Tool Configuration" for the Maven version you installed.

Once doing the above this should work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the correct `maven tool name` but not the correct `Server ID` of your artifactory.

If you are not sure about the `artifactory serverID`, you may alternatively specify the artifactory using `artifactory server address`.

```
  def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'YOUR_ARTIFACTORY_URL', username: 'ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME', password: 'ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD'
```